# what -Dcom.sun.enterprise.server.ss.ASQuickStartup does

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, glassfish-3

I am using Glassfish 3.1. When searching forums and articles about GF tuning I have found that I should set -Dcom.sun.enterprise.server.ss.ASQuickStartup to false.
But unfortunately in any place I could find any description what it does do.
Please, anyone knows?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old setting which was used in GlassFish v2 to disable the async startup mechanism of the Grizzly HTTP component (false to disable).

In GlassFish v3 and v4 this setting does nothing.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I have already read all comments to this bug: https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-5321?focusedCommentId=103168&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-103168 and yes, it says it won't be maintained in version 3

Comment: Isn't an async setting good for handling more clients than the number of threads? Of course depending on the nature of the application.